# Silex Security Provider - Token failing to be set

Tags: php, authentication, silex

I'm working for the first time with Silex's Security Provider and I'm having issues with the process. I currently have the basic HTTP auth working (using the coded example user as shown [here in the docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#securing-a-path-with-http-authentication)).

When switching HTTP out for the form option however the login form is submitting, and returning to itself. I have created a `UserProvider` class and the `loadUserByUsername` method is being successfully called, however the email isn't being passed in (being set to `"NONE_PROVIDED"` - altered from username). This I found when working through the vendor code is because the token isn't being set (`$app['security']->getToken()` returning null at all points). I've trawled through all the docs I can but I can't find any mention of this.

The main code is included below, let me know if there is anything else, thanks!

**Security Provider Configuration**

```
// Protects all routes within /auth, redirecting to /login successfully

$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'unauth_area' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/(?!auth)'
        ),
        'auth_area' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/.*$',
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/login',
                'check_path' => '/auth/login_check',
                'default_target_path' => '/auth/overview',
            ),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                return new UserProvider($app['db']);
            }),
        ),
    ),
    'access_control' => array(
        array('path' => '^/.*$', 'role' => 'ROLE_USER'),
        // Include the following line to also secure the /admin path itself
        // array('path' => '^/admin$', 'role' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
    ),
));
```

**(My Custom) method - UserProvider class**

```
public function loadUserByUsername($email) {

    // Dying at this point shows it reaches here, but $email is null

    $stmt = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', array(strtolower($email)));

    if (!$user = $stmt->fetch()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Email "%s" does not exist.', $email));
    }

    return new User($user['email'], $user['password'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);
}
```

**Form Class**

```
class LoginType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('_username', 'text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Email(),
            )
        ))
        ->add('_password', 'password', array(
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
            ),
        ))
        ->add('Login', 'submit');
}

public function getName() {
    return 'login';
}
```

}

[Silex Security Provider docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html)

Comment: Could you also post your form? Is the username element still called "_username"?

Comment: Also, just to make sure, check this: `If you're using a form to authenticate users, you need to enable SessionServiceProvider.`

Comment: I've included the form, I've reverted it to "_username" in an attempt to get it working (I reached the stage of aimless tinkering so I've tried all sorts). The dependency is included (composer) and the security provider is registered, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Apologies, just re-read that, but the session provider is also enabled yes (and is registered before the security provider)

Comment: And do you still get an empty $email passed to `UserProvider ::loadUserByUsername($email)` with the form input field set to _username?

Comment: Yeah, trying to output the value in `loadUserByusername` after each tweak, but each time I only get the string 'NONE_PROVIDED', which is set in `UserAuthenticationProvider::authenticate` (the method expects a token that doesn't appear to ever get set)

Comment: I tried outputting the token directly in the `authenticate` method and it is at least created, but the credentials are null

Comment: I see your "password" field is called `password` instead of `_password` which might throw off the authenticate function.

Comment: I've tried many a time (that's what it currently is now actually)

Comment: Does the actual form (the generated form) post to the proper login_check url `/auth/login_check`?

Comment: It does yes, ends on that page when i'm outputting the $email variable with a die()

Comment: At this point, everything seems to be in order. Could you enable a logger ([Monolog](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/monolog.html) for example) and inspect the log?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2cp81vl/8 - This is the output I received (never used Monolog actually). Hasn't really told me much. Getting majorly frustrating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the token… I just had the same problem with

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/admin',
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/', 
                'check_path' => '/admin/login_check', 
                'username_parameter'=> 'mail',
                'password_parameter' => 'password',
                 ),
                'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/logout'),
                    //'anonymous' => true,
            'users' => function () use ($app) {
                return new UserProvider($app['db']);
            },
        )
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(
            array('^/$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'),
            array('^/admin', 'ROLE_USER')
        )
));
```

After a couple hours trying and testing, I checked the name attribute in my form's input… Saw `form[mail]`

So I tried

```
'username_parameter'=> 'form[mail]',
'password_parameter' => 'form[password]',
```

And … ALLELUIA!!!!! had my mail in `loadUserByUsername($mail)`